# Ambiguous source reflection for through association error? (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So i've been getting this when running my Capybara automation tests, Im not super familiar with rails...but based on the error im assuming it has something to do with the "model".

Here is the error(With some name changes):

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: Ambiguous source reflection for through association.  Please specify a :source directive on your declaration like:

  class Stuff < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :things, {:through=>:foo, :source=>"bar"}
```

here is what exists in the model file for "Stuff":

```
has_many :things, through: :foo
```

What exactly does this mean, I notice in the error it's showing a :source=>"bar", which doesn't exist in the model currently. So it's saying it doesn't no where :things comes from? Rails is very new to me so I don't understand what exactly it's saying? And google doesn't seem to turn up this error much unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is telling you the relationship between `Stuff` and `Thing` is ambiguous because you haven't defined the relationship between `Stuff` and `Foo`. This typically looks like this:

```
class Student
  has_many :scheduled_classes
  has_many :teachers, through: :scheduled_classes
end

class ScheduledClass
  belongs_to :student
  belongs_to :teacher
end

class Teacher
  has_many :scheduled_classes
  has_many :students, through: :scheduled_classes
end
```

Note that the `through` value is named after a relationship on the same class.

Comment: Well I noticed in my models file im missing the ":source =: "bar" is that not relevant here? since thats what the error was saying.

Comment: @msmith1114 The `source` is implicit usually, you only need it in cases where there's actual ambiguity. It looks like, in your case, you simply haven't defined the base relationship yet.

Comment: Maybe im mis-understanding what you mean by "defined base relationship". There is actually a has_many :foo defined below it. In the class Stuff file.

Comment: @msmith1114 You *might* need to reorder those relationships. This is Ruby code, which is executing linearly at runtime. Rails autoloading might be preventing the issue from showing up under dev conditions.